# Roman numbers in front matter thesis

Tags: typography

This is a follow-up question of this one:

[What page numbering conventions are there for front matters (prelims) of books?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13719/what-page-numbering-conventions-are-there-for-front-matters-prelims-of-books)

If I were to use roman numbers, should they be in small or capital letters?  I've seen this changes when using `babel` in `spanish` or `english` with LaTeX, but I'm not sure if this is because of a graphic design guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of stylistic convention, not design rules. Styles and style guides vary from language to language, country to country and publication to publication, but in English-language publishing the consistent practice is to use lowercase Roman numerals for front matter folios (page numbers). The [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html) -- a commonly-used style guide in the United States -- specifies this. I don't recall ever seeing a professionally-published English-language book that used uppercase Roman numerals for front matter folios.